# How would I remove multiple nested values from a hash

Tags: ruby

I've got a really confusing question that I can't seem to figure out.

Say I have this hash

```
hash = {
 "lock_version"=>1, 
 "exhibition_quality"=>false,
 "within"=>["FID6", "S5"], 
 "representation_file"=>{
    "lock_version"=>0, 
    "created_by"=>"admin", 
    "within"=>["FID6", "S5"]
  }
}
```

How can I delete from `"within"=>["FID6", "S5"]` a value with the pattern `FID<Number>` (in this example `FID6`)?

I've thought about it a bit and used the .delete, .reject! the within but I realised this was deleting the whole key value pair which is not what I want. Thanks a lot for any help that can put me on the right path.

Comment: When you give an example it is always helpful to show the desired result as a complete Ruby object. Here I expect it to be the same hash except the two instances of `"within"=>["FID6", "S5"]` are replaced with `"within"=>["S5"]`, but there would be no doubt about your objective it you showed the desired result (hash). Also, readers will assume you don't want to modify ("mutate") the original hash unless you specifically say you want to. You don't say that but mention two methods (`delete` and `reject!`) that do mutate the hash. It's best to always be clear about that.

Comment: If you found any answer helpful consider [selecting the one you preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method or proc/lambda to achieve the result. This solutions splits up the logic in two parts. Removing the actual `FID<Number>` string from the array and recursively calling the former on the correct key.

```
remove_fid = ->(array) { array.grep_v(/\AFID\d+\z/) }

remove_nested_fid = lambda do |hash|
  hash.merge(
    hash.slice('within').transform_values(&remove_fid),
    hash.slice('representation_file').transform_values(&remove_nested_fid)
  )
end

pp hash.then(&remove_nested_fid) # or remove_nested_fid.call(hash)
# {"lock_version"=>1,
#  "exhibition_quality"=>false,
#  "within"=>["S5"],
#  "representation_file"=>
#   {"lock_version"=>0, "created_by"=>"admin", "within"=>["S5"]}}
```

[`grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) removes all strings from the array that do not match the given regex.

[`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) creates a new hash only containing the given keys. If a key is missing it will not be present in the resulting hash.

[`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) transforms the values of a hash into a new value (similar to `map` for Array), returning a hash.

[`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) creates a new hash, merging the hashes together.

This solution does not mutate the original `hash` structure.

Comment: Nice to see the rarely-used `grep_v`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to recurse over the Hash and, in cases where the value is a Hash, process it using the same function, repeatedly. This can be problematic in Ruby -- which doesn't handle recursion very well -- if the depth of the tree is too deep, but it's the most natural way to express this type of issue.

```rb
def filter_fids(h)
    h.each_pair do |k, v|
        if v.is_a? Hash
            filter_fids v
        elsif k == "within"
            v.reject! { |x| x.start_with? "FID" }
        end
    end
end
```

This will mutate the original data structure in place.

Comment: Note that the question specifies `FID<Number>`, so presumably nothing is to be changed in `"within"=>["FIDGETED", "S5"]`, but you remove all strings that begin with `"FID"`. Of course, you can fix that with `x.match?(/\AFID\d+\z/)`.